# the android device is connected to the wamp server but doesn't show anything in listview

Tags: android, listview, wamp, emulation, device

there is my code for setting my localhost wamp server IP:

```
public class JSONCommands {

    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.119.1/ketabha/services.php?op=";
    ...
}
```

with this URL my emulator is showing the elements in my books list but my Lenovo tablet is just opening a blank activity! and doesn't show the book items in that!! but there is no error or something!
sorry for my bad English , Pleas help.

Comment: Give us some code..we are not wizards. How can we know the problem if you only give us the URL?

Comment: `but there is no error or something!` it is prolly becuase you swallow all exception like old porn's star (`catch(Exception ex) {}`)

Comment: I said dear it works in my emulator! my tablet is connected to my PC and my wamp server is on!
Code about what?! @BlazeTama

Comment: `it works in my emulator! my tablet is connected to my PC` and? does tablet is using the same subnet ?

Comment: no answer @Selvin you have a very low rank of humanity.

Comment: I got headache here...there is no error doesnt mean there is nothing wrong with your code. Theres a lot of possibility your listview is empty. And dont use "!", we are here to help and you does NOT pay us.

Comment: @NiloofarHakkaki why you, meatbags(you have to said it, nice irony), do not understand the basics ... emulator and your PC shares the same subnet - your device and PC not ... the `192.168.119.1` means nothing for your tablet and you have host not found or other exception ... which is no showing anywhere becuase ... you know why(my first comment)

Comment: are ok with reading my Question at the first place? @BlazeTama you can do not answer if you didn't get the problem honey. there is no force!!!!!

Comment: just check this: put on you server some static html and check if you can get it from: emulator's and tablet's standard web browser `http://192.168.119.1/ketabha/somestatic.htm`

Comment: I did every things that were in internet and stackoverflow for connecting my device to the wamp server. tell me about basics!!! @Selvin

Comment: Have you changed your Apache `httpd.conf` file to allow access from ip's other than the one that is running Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the wamp server just need to restart after turning off the fire wall and setting local IP in APP.